# How do I upload a photo / image to LinkedIn via API?

Tags: file-upload, linkedin-api

LinkedIn has a /share API endpoint which accepts a link and a message. The link is afterwards expanded to an OpenGraph card and that gives you a way to stick an image preview in there, but it seems there's no other way to upload an image/picture to LinkedIn feed like you can do in the web app itself.

Is there a way, private API, undocumented endpoint or some other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a rich media share is done in two steps. First, the media is uploaded to LinkedIn's media platform. Then, a personal or organization share referencing that media is created.

This URL might be help you.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares#upload

Comment: That url [Rich media shares](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares#upload) is really excellent.

Comment: The Rich Media Platform currently used to upload images and create rich media shares has been marked for deprecation by `January 30, 2020` | heres the new way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#register-an-upload-for-images

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to give us the URL and we'll scrape it (or pull it from our cache).

Comment: For now, when someone posts an image in our app (we are social networks publishing app, like Buffer. http://amplifr.com/en ), we craft a url of the image itself, upload it to s3 and do a bit of magic to upload the image thumbnail.

Comment: What we want to do, is to be able to upload photos via API. Users can upload photos directly to Linkedin via web and mobile apps. Apparently, it's not possible at the moment with the public API, so we'd need to intercept what web/mobile app does. Which is not fun at all ;(

Comment: Hey, has this changed?  Is there any way to share just an image via API without requiring a link-url?

Comment: Would like to know if this is available or even on the roadmap? We're an app that shares photos of people at events (ie job fairs, networking events, etc) on social networks. A lot of people would like to post their images to LinkedIn, but as it is, we can only post the image as the small image in the Open Graph object. Would it be possible to just straight up make an image upload?

Comment: I saw on [HubSpot](https://hubspot.uservoice.com/forums/76407-general-hubspot-ideas/suggestions/6263915-attach-an-image-to-linkedin-posts) that LinkedIn recently released an API for uploading images. Any idea when the documentation will be available?

Comment: Any updates on this? Sometimes all we have is array of bytes (of image obviously) which we need to upload and share on social network. Facebook and Twitter already have this functionality, would love to have it on Linkedin too :-)

Comment: Any update to this yet, I still dont see the API anywhere?