# Is it possible to upload an image to LinkedIn via the LinkedIn Share API, or LinkedIn's API in general?

Tags: image, linkedin-api

I have long since figured out how to share a link to the image itself, it generates a proper preview, title, etc.

However I'd like to know if there is an endpoint for uploading the image to LinkedIn's image hosting similar to Facebook.

Alternatively, it would be great if there are meta tags that can be set in the image's header to tell the scraper to grab the image instead of just treating it as link.

Uploading pictures with Facebook's API looks something like this (Javascript):

```
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {message: shareMsg, url:imgURL }, function(response) {
  //response handling
});
```

From the few other questions I found asking similar things, it appears as if it may not be directly possible through the web API, however I have not yet found an answer as to whether or not meta tags can be set so LinkedIn pulls the image onto their site.

[Publishing an Image Without a Related URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340483/publishing-an-image-without-a-related-url-via-the-linkedin-api)

[How do I Upload a Photo Image to LinkedIn Via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053529/how-do-i-upload-a-photo-image-to-linkedin-via-api)

Thank you for your time.